# A terse way of saying "this class overrides all necessary methods to be non-abstract"

Tags: c++, subclass, virtual-functions

I have a base class `Base` with quite a few pure-virtual methods, and I want to define a few classes of the form `class Foo: public Base` and similarly `class Bar`, `class Baz` etc - all of which should be non-virtual, and all of which implementing their virtual methods in .cpp file, not inline in the class definition. Currently, in each one of these classes' definition I declare `void method1() override`, `void method2() override` etc. ad nauseam - and I have to copy-paste this stuff as many times as I inherit `class Base`.

Is there another, more succinct way of saying "this class overrides all necessary methods to be non-abstract"?

**Notes:**

- I know I could do some macro-based kludge, I don't mean that.
- Solutions based on C++ reflection libraries are not preferable but might be acceptable.
- You can ignore multiple inheritance if it helps.

Comment: You ask weird questions man. Can you stuff that with a (pseudo code) example of what you actually want to achieve please?

Comment: Did you mean "all necessary methods to be non-abstract"?

Comment: "*this class overrides all necessary methods to be non-virtual*" You're still going to have to provide *definitions* for them. So you need to provide declarations too, if you don't declare and define them in the same place.

Comment: @NicolBolas: The definitions go in the .cpp ; I just want to have a class definition with less cluster, e.g. "this class overrides everything it needs to, plus here's a couple of other members & methods" rather than "this class has methods method1 and method2 and method3 and etc."

Comment: @PreferenceBean: Yes, I meant abstract/pure virtual.

Answer (score 2):

No.

You must state each function you wish to override.

There is no way to auto-declare all overridable functions from each base.

If this is a problem, that's a good indicator that your interfaces have too many member functions.

Don't forget the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)!